# Pasando como parametro el numero (número único) - master/detail

Tags: android, recyclerview

Tengo un problema que tengo a la hora de trabajar con el *master/detail flow*.

Tengo mi clase principal (`MainActivity`), este es un `AppCompanyActivity`, y dentro de este tengo un `ViewPager` que tiene 2 vistas que son `Fragments`. Una de ellas tiene una conexión con `Volley` y `Gson`, que parsean un **`JSON`** y se guarda en un `List`. En este caso algo así, (`List<CFAlumnos> =`....) esta lista se extrae de un servicio web creado por mí mismo, el cual solo tiene los campos de nombre y número. Todo va bien, el servicio se consume con éxito, el problema es cuando doy *click* a uno de los registros. Quiero que la siguiente pantalla sea un *master/detail* pasando como parámetro el número (número único) para así posteriormente en ese *master/detail* hacer otra conexión y comparar al parámetro con una nueva lista donde me mostrarán los detalles completos del `Alumno`. ¿Me he explicado?  He intentado almacenar toda la información en ese `List` y pasarlo como parámetro, pero no he tenido éxito.

***Fragment*** que tiene la conexión *Volley*.

```
private void requestJsonObject(){

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    String url ="http://15.54.34.22/PlatinumMovilBD/controller/docentes.php/docentes_alumnos?txtname=05";

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Response " + response);
            //JSONObject phone = response.get("phone");
            GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
            Gson mGson = builder.create();
            JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
            JsonObject rootObejct = parser.parse(response).getAsJsonObject();
            JsonElement projectElement = rootObejct.get("alumnos");
            alumnos = new ArrayList<CFAlumnos>();
            alumnos = Arrays.asList(mGson.fromJson(projectElement, CFAlumnos[].class));

            adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), alumnos);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error " + error.getMessage());
        }
    });

    queue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

---

```
public class RecyclerViewHolders extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        public TextView matricula;
        public TextView nombre;

        public RecyclerViewHolders(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            matricula = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.matricula);
            nombre = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nombre);
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Context context = view.getContext();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
            final Intent string = intent.putExtra("string", alumnos.get(getPosition()));
            context.startActivity(intent);
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "position = " + getPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

---

*Master/Detail* -- Aquí quiero recibir ese parámetro que lo he conseguido, pero no puedo hacer una conexión. Más bien, no sé si hago bien en hacer una conexión aquí.

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
       // setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

       para_matricula =  getIntent().getExtras().getString("string");
     TextView m = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.matricula);
     m.setText(para_matricula);
     setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
     final ImageView imagen_Appbar = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.image);

     imagen_Appbar.setImageResource(R.drawable.logup);
     getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
     CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
}
```

---

Aquí trato de hacer lo mismo que en el `fragment`, pero como es un `AppCompanyActivity`, quiero hacerlo con el `recyclerView`.

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String para_matricula;
    private final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
    private RecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

     //Aquí no me deja trabajar
     View drawer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view, container, false);
     recyclerView = (RecyclerView) drawer.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
     recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SimpleDividerItemDecoration(DetailActivity.this));
     recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(DetailActivity.this));

       para_matricula =  getIntent().getExtras().getString("string");
       TextView m = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.matricula);
       m.setText(para_matricula);
       setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
       final ImageView imagen_Appbar = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.image);
```

Comment: Hola!, primero trata de expresar de mejor manera tu problema. Segundo, deja tu codigo para que podamos ayudarte con mejor detalle.

Comment: Si gracias por responder trate de subir las imagenes pero como soy nuevo en esto no me permitió. Tengo una lista que trabaja con recyclerview todo eso va bien mi duda esta en pasar un parametro para que la siguiente actividad en este caso master/detail y en esta vista poder hacer otra conexión que muestre el contenido segun el parametro, si me explico?

Comment: No subas imagenes, sube codigo. Si yo entiendo lo que necesitas pero agrega tu codigo para ayudarte aun mas

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agrega todo ese codigo, evita botos negativos o cierre de la pregunta

Comment: Si gracias lo intento ahora mismo..

Comment: que falla cuando intentas pasar `final Intent string = intent.putExtra("string", alumnos.get(getPosition()));` ??

Comment: Nada de hecho a la hora de recibir ese parámetro en la siguiente vista no me muestra esa posición en el m.settetex(para_matricula);, trabajo con un fragment y el master/detail es un  AppCompatActivity. enseguida subire mas codigo. Gracias por responder !!

Answer (score 0):

Intenta hacer algo parecido a esto:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
{
            MainActivity Main = new MainActivity();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();

            extras.putString("valor1",objeto.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtras(extras);
            extras.putString("valor2", objeto.getText().toString());
            extras.putBoolean("valorn", true);

            intent.putExtras(extras);

            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Aqui recibes tus parametros:

```
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        boolean istrue= getIntent().getBooleanExtra("valorn", false);
        if (istrue)
        {
            String var1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("valor1");///getIntent().getStringExtra(
            String var2= getIntent().getStringExtra("valor2");

            hacerAlgo(var1,var2);
        }
```

Haz uso del log para que visualices el resultado en Android Monitor

```
Log.i("MITAG","valor a mostrar en el log");
```